# Wi-Fi speeds are capped at 54 Mb/s, even though I get 833 Mb/s when the same computer is booted to Windows 10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

Currently I am using a Wi-Fi 6 PCIe card (Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz) with the firmware `46.3cfab8da.0 op_mode iwlmvm` loaded.

My connection's link speed shows as 54 Mb/s (5.7 GHz), even though it should be much faster. When I boot my computer to Windows 10 for example, I get a link speed of 833 Mb/s with a speed test clocking in at roughly 500-700 MB/s. On Ubuntu 20.04, the download speed is consistently capped at 22-23 Mb/s. My kernel version is 5.5 (I've also tried 5.4 and it did not change anything).

If there is any additional information I can provide, please let me know. Please also let me know if I should format my question/system information in a certain way to make it easier to troubleshoot.

Here is the output to `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev d0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev d0)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z97 Chipset LPC Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41)
06:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 12)
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
```

Things that I have tried so far

1. `sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`
2. Changing the MTU of my wireless connection from 1500 to 1492 using `ifconfig wlp7s0 mtu 1492` (without rebooting, only disconnect/reconnect). `sudo ip link set dev wlp7s0 mtu 1492` also did not work (except switching my connection from 5.7ghz to 2.4 ghz).

Comment: What's your MTU? `ip link show`. For WiFi, it should be `1492`, not `1500`. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Hi, I've edited my post. Please let me know if there is any other information/formatting change that would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Read the `man pages`. Try `sudo ip link set dev w1p7s0 mtu 1492`. `ifconfig` is being supplanted by `ip`.

Comment: Hi, that seemed to slow my connection a little bit (the link speed is still 54 mb/s but the connection switched from 5.7ghz to 2.4ghz)